# Docker networking issue - write unixgram ->: write: no buffer space available

Tags: macos, docker, kernel

I have an issue with running a `docker build bake` on a macos, but I think it's related to the OS and not to Docker.
During the execution of the build - I get a "Connection was reset" exceptions for `apt-get` or `wget` or anything related to internet.

After investigating Docker's logs, I seen these logs -

```
2023-07-16 15:26:14.921972+0300  localhost com.docker.backend[2357]: tx 0 dropping packet length 21634: write unixgram ->: write: no buffer space available
2023-07-16 15:26:14.922294+0300  localhost com.docker.backend[2357]: tx 0 dropping packet length 32834: write unixgram ->: write: no buffer space available
2023-07-16 15:26:14.922501+0300  localhost com.docker.backend[2357]: tx 0 dropping packet length 32834: write unixgram ->: write: no buffer space available
2023-07-16 15:26:14.922549+0300  localhost com.docker.backend[2357]: tx 0 dropping packet length 22150: write unixgram ->: write: no buffer space available
2023-07-16 15:26:14.922574+0300  localhost com.docker.backend[2357]: tx 0 dropping packet length 21634: write unixgram ->: write: no buffer space available
2023-07-16 15:26:14.922612+0300  localhost com.docker.backend[2357]: tx 0 dropping packet length 32834: write unixgram ->: write: no buffer space available
2023-07-16 15:26:14.922648+0300  localhost com.docker.backend[2357]: tx 0 dropping packet length 32834: write unixgram ->: write: no buffer space available
2023-07-16 15:26:14.922682+0300  localhost com.docker.backend[2357]: tx 0 dropping packet length 32834: write unixgram ->: write: no buffer space available
```

and I am pretty sure this is the issue, but I have no idea how to solve it...

I am running on MacOS M1 pro, with 32 GB ram, and I don't understand why there is no buffer space...

any ideas how to solve this issue?